# making ccsprites from an array of strings

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsarray

I have made a method that matches string objects to each member of an enum in an array. I would like to add sprites to each member of the bArray matching with their respective strings as sprite images. How can I do this?

```
+ (NSArray *)names
{
    static NSMutableArray * _names = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
        [_names insertObject:@"image1.png" atIndex:image1];
        [_names insertObject:@"image2.png" atIndex:image2];
        [_names insertObject:@"image3.png" atIndex:image3];
        [_names insertObject:@"image4.png" atIndex:image4];
        [_names insertObject:@"image5.png" atIndex:image5];
        [_names insertObject:@"image6.png" atIndex:image6];
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
    });

    return _names;
}

-(void)spriteGroups    {
    NSArray* sgArray;
    sgArray = [[spManager names] objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)]];
    CCSprite* groupSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[sgArray[0]]];// this gives me an expected identifier error. I guess this is not the right way
    for (int i = 1; i > [sgArray count]; i++) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove extra square brackets around `sgArray`

```
CCSprite* groupSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:sgArray[0]];
```